Ansible task to Toggle a file's encryption status (encrypted/decrypted) using ternary
I am attempting to use ansible to toggle the encryption state of a specified file (encrypt the file if decrypted, decrypt it if encrypted) using the ansible filter "ternary".
This is my playbook:
---
# site.yml

- name: site playbook (dummy site)
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    file:   test_key_file
    cmd_encrypt: ansible-vault encrypt {{ file }}
    cmd_decrypt: ansible-vault decrypt {{ file }}

  tasks:
    - local_action: shell
      head -1 {{ file }} | grep -v -q \$ANSIBLE_VAULT | ternary( "{{ cmd_encrypt }}" , "{{ cmd_decrypt }}"  )


The first part of the shell command was taken from here. I added the ternary part. I have tried various modifications regarding quotes and curly-braces, and substituting values for variables to no avail.
The configuration above results in the error:
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  could not find expected ':'

The error appears to be in '/home/sjf/toggle_encryption_test/site.yml': line 16, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    - local_action: shell
      head -1 {{ file }} | grep -v -q \$ANSIBLE_VAULT | ternary( "{{ cmd_encrypt }}" , "{{ cmd_decrypt }}"  )
^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"

Any help would be appreciated.

The line works through the grep section.

ternary is an ansible filter. You can't use that as a shell command.

You could do something like this with set_fact module. vault_cmd: "{{ (lookup('pipe', 'head -1 ' + file)) is search('$ansible_vault',ignorecase=True) | ternary( cmd_decrypt , cmd_encrypt )  }}" Then use the shell command to execute using the fact variable that was created.

Your very first problem is that your yaml is not valid. Do yourself a favor: drop usage of local_action in favor of a normally written shell task simply containing the option delegate_to: localhost (although none are of any use here since your are targetting localhost anyway....). For the rest, see @Squashman comments.

Forgot that the search is regular expression. You probably would want to do this: '^\\$ansible_vault;' for the expression to find.

Squashman - that worked. Enter it as a solution and I'll give you credit.
